# Extract rows from one google sheet to another based on criteria in column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet called "Senate." In Column E, some of the rows have "ID" in that column. I would like to copy the rows that contain "ID" in Column E and paste them into another sheet called "Targets." It is important the rows are not taken from the original sheet "Senate"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that with 'sheet' you do mean sheet (tab) and NOT a spreadsheet (workbook), in sheet Targets, A1 try:

```
=query(Senate!A:Z, "where E = 'ID' ",1)
```

Change range to suit.